# Rails+Herokuでpackage.jsonのdependenciesがdeployされない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, npm

Railsプロジェクトをherokuにdeployして開発しております。
dev環境でpackage.jsonを下記のようにして作業できていたのですが、

```
{
  "name": "app-rails",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "primer-css": "^9.6.0"
  }
}
```

deployしたところ、`File to import not found or unreadable: primer-css/index.scss.`になりました。
`heroku run cat package.json`で確認したところ、dependenciesが反映されていませんでした。

```
{
  "name": "app-rails",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

dependenciesが反映されないのは設定が足りていないなどあるのでしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

applicaiton.css ➜ application.scss

`@import "primer-css/index.scss";` ➜　`@import "primer-css/index";`

にしたら、通りました。設定ミスのようでした申し訳ありません、